# Changing item name when being added to cart?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Magento 2.4.6

I am using the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event to modify the price of the product which is added to the cart. This works just fine. Changing the name however does not work. I tried with:

```
$item->setName('whatever');
```

Gives no errors, but also does not change a thing. I found some hints on the net, but they all use another event. Is there a way to change the name if the product added to the cart using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event?

Thanks!